# Android crash on configuration change

Tags: java, android, fragment

so i am making a password manager app for android and i have 1 activity and fragments im using room for sql and all of that works fine but when i rotate the screen the app crashes and im not sure why, it says that it cant find the constructor on the configuration change but if that was the case why would it work in the first place :(

the fragment code

```
package app.web.fragments.passwords;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

import app.web.R;
import app.web.room_password.Password;
import app.web.view_model.PasswordViewModel;

public class Password_Add_Fragment extends Fragment {

private EditText username, password;
// priority is number picker
private NumberPicker numberPicker;
private Button insert, yeetAll;
private PasswordViewModel passwordViewModel;

private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;

public Password_Add_Fragment(FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics){
    this.firebaseAnalytics = firebaseAnalytics;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container==null){
        return null;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_passwords_by_category, container, false);

    setButtons(view);

    return view;
}

private void setButtons(View view) {

    passwordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(PasswordViewModel.class);
    username = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_add_username);
    password = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_add_password);
    numberPicker = view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_priority_password);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
    insert = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_password_save);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String usernameP = username.getText().toString().trim();
            String passwordP = password.getText().toString().trim();
            int x = numberPicker.getValue();

            if (!usernameP.isEmpty() && !passwordP.isEmpty() && x >= 1){
                Password passwordX = new Password(usernameP,passwordP,x);
                passwordViewModel.insert(passwordX);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    yeetAll = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_password_delete_all);
    yeetAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            passwordViewModel.deleteAllPasswords();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted All", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

the crash log

[Full crash log](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3160af754ec55326f10af695e9bf75720210610142247/8b0915)

Answer (score 0):

nevermind the fix was to just have an empty constructor in the fragment class.